# NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground not firing in extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, notificationcenter

I have a simple password extension that works great, except I need reliable notification when the app hosting the extension moves to the background.  My understanding is that the NSExtensionHostxyz notifications should work.  The code is setup per the below, but I never see the notification come in.

My extension presents a small user interface and in its viewWillAppear, I have this code:

self.observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground, object:nil, queue: nil) { (notif) in
        NSLog("observer fired")
    }

The view controller for the extension is declared:
class ExtViewController: ASCredentialProviderViewController

I have tried the normal objC selector addObserver, using the extensionContext as 'object', and several other variations and no success.  Any ideas?